# What is the ember way to add popovers to views?

Tags: ember.js

I'm working on a events board app. Events are displayed in columns at the height matching the start time and pack into the space if there is more then one overlapping. Each event is a view and I want to have a div next to the view that shows and hides on hover.

I know how to bind to mouseEnter and mouseLeave to show and hide part of the template but I want to show something adjacent to my view/template not within it.

I've already got some computed properties on the view to place the event with the correct height and width so I don't want to add the popover inside the view.

Here is something to mess with http://jsbin.com/osoner/1/edit

Seems like something simple but I want to make sure I'm doing things the Ember way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After messing a little with your provided jsbin, [here the results](http://jsbin.com/osoner/8/edit).
Basically what I've done was adding a new `popup` css declaration wich do position the popup so that it appears outside the parent view, and also moved the `{{#if...}}` helper into the originating view.

If you want to go more fancy, checkout this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/74qjR/) wich uses the *twitter boostrap popover*.

Hope it helps.